# Returned rejected promises and onPossiblyUnhandledRejection handler in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm writing a lot of code with this pattern, and a similar example can be found in Bluebird's [documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise):

```
var promise4 = Promise.join(promise1, promise2, function (value1, value2) {
  // promise 3 needs the values resolved from promise1 and promise2
  return promise3(value1, value2);
});
```

My error handling is done like this:

```
Promise.all([
  promise4
])
.catch(function (err) {
  // handle error
});
```

The problem is that if promise3 gets rejected, it will trigger bluebird's onPossiblyUnhandledRejection handler because it was rejected before it was attached to any promise chain (with error handling). This results in big error messages getting printed out constantly when nothing is actually wrong.

I'm not sure what to do about this because on the one hand, the above pattern is extremely useful for constructing concurrent logic and is very easy to understand, but on the other hand I don't want to simply override onPossiblyUnhandledRejection because it could be useful if I do actually forget to handle something.

[bluebird's documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling) kind of addresses this issue, in a way that makes it sound as if the above pattern is an odd one:

"if your code for some reason needs to swoop in and attach error handler to some promise after the promise has been hanging around a while then you will see annoying messages"

My "some reason" is that I need to build highly concurrent software. Is this a fundamental flaw in how I'm approaching this kind of problem? If not, how should I resolve this without removing these warnings entirely?

Comment: Please show in your code where (and when) you actually attach the error handler to the chain.

Comment: So your error handler is called *and* you get the unhandled-rejection event, at about the same time? That sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes, this happens in numerous places in my app, but the error is always caught successfully. If it changes anything promise3 might be something that gets immediately rejected such as a Promise.try with synchronous logic.

Comment: @TomO'Connell I can't reproduce it - can you create a minimal test case (preferably without external dependencies) recreating the issue?

Comment: Yeah, this really sounds like a bug. Can you make a minimal executable example, and [file an issue](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues)?

Comment: Your code looks fine it's idiomatic bluebird - either you actually have an unhandled rejection you're not dealing with somewhere or there is a bug - also please make sure you're on the latest bluebird (I think that's 2.9.8)

Comment: Can you also show the interaction between creating `promise3` and attaching the error handler?

Comment: Sure, I'll create an example as soon as possible. I just updated bluebird btw (I was on 2.6.4) and it did change something. Now I'm getting Unhandled rejection errors instead of Possibly unhandled errors.

Comment: Update: This was a bug in code the OP did not post in the question.

Comment: @TomO'Connell lol - petka just changed the name from possibly unhandled error to unhandled rejection today because he thinks it's a better nanme :D

Comment: Half the time you are treating `promise3` as a promise and half the time you are treating it like a function, which one is it? Can you provide more accurate representation of the real code as this will not cause unhandled rejection

Comment: Thanks everyone that contributed.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented your code works just fine without reporting unhandled rejection:

```
function promise3(value1, value2) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("the error"))    
}
var promise1 = Promise.resolve();
var promise2 = Promise.resolve();
var promise4 = Promise.join(promise1, promise2, function (value1, value2) {
  // promise 3 needs the values resolved from promise1 and promise2
  return promise3(value1, value2);
});

Promise.all([promise4]).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message === "the error")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hx0zdd2/

What's more likely is that you have forgotten a `return` statement somewhere which is needed to wire promises together and make chaining (and error propagation) work.

Comment: I tend to agree with you because I constructed my own isolated example and don't see the issue. I haven't found anything wrong with my actual code yet though.

Comment: @TomO'Connell Can you try enabling long stack traces and following the trace. For instance in this jsfiddle I forgot the return but you can follow the logged trace to see where it happened http://jsfiddle.net/6hx0zdd2/1/

Comment: Just tried this. The rejected promise is definitely being returned in all cases. Still hunting for the cause. I think I should mention again that my error handling is actually working as expected. The place I'm seeing this issue right now is when I'm running my mocha tests for my API with intentionally faulty data. The errors get caught and handled as expected but I still see this message.

Comment: I figured it out. It was because my error handler was in a different module than the place where the promise chain began.

Comment: @TomO'Connell nvm I saw you updated... it's just that 2.8.0+ with long traces should make it really easy to find where the unhandled error originates from

Comment: The problem was, I actually forgot that I was initiating the promise chain elsewhere. Thanks for getting me on the right track for this, I'm glad to know it was just my dumb error.

Comment: @TomO'Connell np. Btw the documentation is a bit outdated, it is now clear that code  attaching  catch handlers asynchronously can always be refactored (as in not changing behavior, concurrency or what not) into code that doesn't cause false positives. It will be fixed in 3.0 docs which are hosted at a website